# ES6 Set - How to iterate to previous value?

Tags: ecmascript-6

In ES6's  **Set**   next Property is available like

```js
var mySet = new Set();
mySet.add("foobar");
mySet.add(1);
mySet.add("baz");

var setIter = mySet.entries();

console.log(setIter.next().value); // ["foobar", "foobar"]
```

How to navigate to the previous property, Is something like below is available?

```js
console.log(setIter.previous().value);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterators do not have a previous function. You can however iterate using `for..of` instead and keep track of the previous value:

```
var mySet = new Set();
mySet.add("foobar");
mySet.add(1);
mySet.add("baz");

let previous;
for(const current of mySet.entries()) {
  console.log(previous, current);
  previous = current;
}
```

Then you can wrap in a function which returns a generator like so:

```
var mySet = new Set();
mySet.add("foobar");
mySet.add(1);
mySet.add("baz");

const previousNextIterator = theSet => {
  return {
    previous: undefined,
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
      for(const e of theSet.entries()) {
        yield e;
        this.previous = e;
      }
    }
  };
};

const iter = previousNextIterator(mySet);
for(const current of iter) {
  console.log(current, iter.previous);
}
```